# Get data from custom post type to another custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I'am wondering if i can do this:

I have a Custom post type with named Staff, there you can create/add your staff.

Then I have another Custom post type called Projects.

When I add a new project i want a list of every Staff, and then choose a staff member that was active in that project.

So how do i get the data from Custom post type Staff to Custom post type Projects?

Comment: You can do this by using the loop and filtering posts related to staff inside a project post. Are you familiar with WP Query? If yes, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129874/attach-one-post-from-one-post-type-to-another-post-from-another-post-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. I use it pretty much on every project.

You can easily create the [Post Object](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/post-object/) or [Relationship](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/) connection. It's a great plugin with detailed documentation.

[Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) is good as well, but last time I used it I needed to add code for connecting Custom Post Types. There wasn't straightforward interface to connect custom post types.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use a plugin like [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/). This will allow you to connect your 2 CPTs together.