# Can I associate a custom post type with another custom post type?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, functions, admin-ui

I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction. I have a custom post type called 'locations'. I have another custom post type called 'testimonials'.

What I'd really like to do is be able to associate a 'testimonial' with a 'location'. So I was trying to figure out if I could some how list those locations within the testimonial post page in the admin area. Almost like a meta box.

I haven't been able to find anything like this anywhere.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you may use "testimonial" custom taxonomy instead of custom post type. Would that help you to achieve goal?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: A custom taxonomy maybe able to be used, however I already have a custom post type with all my locations. Locations have specific details and will need to be added to in the long run.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129874/attach-one-post-from-one-post-type-to-another-post-from-another-post-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You would need to add a custom field that would store the ID of other post type. I would recommend using a select list.

You could try something along these lines:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_143600_add_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', '143600_save_box' );

//create the metabox
function wpse_143600_add_box() {
   add_meta_box( 
    'related_testimonial',
    __( 'Testimonails', 'wpse_143600_translation' ),
    'wpse_143600_testimonial_box',
    'locations',
    'normal'
    );
}

//build the box
function wpse_143600_testimonial_box($post) {

wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'wpse_143600_nonce' );

$wpse_143600_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

$testimonialArgs = array(
'post_type' => 'testimonials',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'numberposts' => -1
);

$testimonials = get_posts($testimonialArgs);

if($testimonials): ?>
<p>
  <label for="meta-select" class="wpse_143600-row-title"><?php _e( 'Example Select Input', 'wpse_143600_translation' )?></label>
  <select name="meta-select" id="meta-select">
    <option value="NULL">Please choose a testimonial…</option>
<?php foreach($testimonials as $testimonial): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $testimonial->ID; ?>" <?php if ( isset ( $wpse_143600_stored_meta['meta-select'] ) ) selected( $wpse_143600_stored_meta['meta-select'][0], $testimonial->ID ); ?>><?php echo $testimonial->post_title; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</p>    
<?php
else:
?>
<p>There are no testimonials - please save this post, and write some testimonials. You'll then be able to choose a testimonial for this location.</p>
<?php
endif;
}

//save the box
function wpse_143600_save_box( $post_id ) {
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'wpse_143600_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'wpse_143600_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}
// Checks for input and saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] ) ) {
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-select', $_POST[ 'meta-select' ] );
}
}
```

That's fairly rough code, but should get you close.

Sorry about the length, you can find it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/zA4aDiV9

Comment: So close!  I'm not sure how to get it to save. I had to revise the code so it showed on the testimonial post type rather than the location post type. See the pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/VjWubfL9

Comment: Any chance you can show me how to save it properly?

Comment: Yes - sorry about the delay.

I mistyped the save function name in the very second line of the code:

`add_action( 'save_post', '143600_save_box' );`

should be

`add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_143600_save_box' );`

In any event, you should change all the wpse_143600 to something a bit more specific to your theme.

Updated code can be found here http://pastebin.com/mr6ym8vs

Hope that gets you there. There are a few other labeling and text changes you'll need to update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [post 2 post](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin by scribu. It does exactly what you want and is the most advanced plugin for that purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use plugins. I was hoping there'd be a function I could add to functions.php.

Comment: This plugin is still working in 2023, very impressive! It's also on GitHub: https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts